# Rampart security configuration with Axis2

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I was wondering what kind of security parameters Rampart accepts. At the moment I'm using this snippet inside my services.xml:

```
<parameter name="OutflowSecurity">
        <action>
            <items>Timestamp Signature Encrypt</items>
            <passwordCallbackClass>org.sc.ws.PWCBHandler</passwordCallbackClass>
            <signaturePropFile>conf/security.properties</signaturePropFile>
            <encryptionUser>client</encryptionUser>
            <user>client</client>
        </action>
</parameter>
```

I'd like to know what other options there are, aside from Timestamp, Signature and Encrypt. Is there a complete list somewhere on the net? A documentation maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here: http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/config.html
Look under Configuration tags, there's a list with all of them.